# subprocess.Popen() not working with Linux

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am using subprocess.Popen() to invoke a subprocess call which should run independently without the parent process waiting for the child process' execution.

I try to send some data structure as a string to the child process, which runs fine on my local windows machine but when I run the same code in an AWS ec2 instance(Linux), it does not get executed. Even though when I run the sample code for subprocess in the same Linux, it executes perfectly.

`````
```parent process```
in_data = {'InstancesInfo': parameters['instances_info'],
                       'external_id': parameters['user_details['external_id'],
                       'role_arn': parameters['user_details']['role_arn'],
                       'org_id': parameters['user_details']['org_id']
                       }

args = json.dumps(in_data)
self.logger.info(CURRENT_OS)
                if CURRENT_OS == 'Linux':
                    self.logger.info("Inside IF")
                    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'RightSizeTypeConverter.py',args], shell=True)
                    self.logger.info("Done")
                else:
                    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'C:\develop\CloudM\AWS\General\RightSizeTypeConverter.py', args], shell=True)
                    print("Done")


```child process file```
```some code````
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("Inside Main")
    instance_list = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    update_right_size_ec2_instances(instance_list)
    logger.info("Inside Main")
`````

I do not get an error message. It's as if everything is working fine

Comment: Hard to guess because what you show is not really a [mcve]. But you use a full path on Windows (and says that it works) and only a relative path on Linux. IMHO, you should try to use an absolute path on Linux, and/or give the absolute path for the Python interpretor.

Comment: I already tried that but no effect.

Comment: Omit `shell=True`. And use an absolute path to `RightSizeTypeConverter.py`. And use `sys.executable` in place of `'python'`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks. It helped.